Vuetify 3 Issue Clearing Styles on unmount
Good Day,
I am running into an issue with Vuetify 3 styling in a dashboard that I'm working on. The particular issue is that when I go to a Vue 3 / vuetify 3 page the styling is loading up fine but the problem that I'm having is that when I navigate to a Vue 2 / vuetify 2 page the vuetify 3 styling is overriding my vuetify 2 styling and not all of the data is being displayed so I need to clear out all of the vuetify 3 styling on page unload.
What I'm currently doing is this but it's not working as the styling is still being carried over to the other Vue 2 page
document.head.querySelectorAll('STYLE').forEach((style) => {
document.head.removeChild(style)

})
This is the way that the page styles are being created
const style = document.createElement('style')
style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css))

onBeforeMount(async () => {
  document.head.appendChild(style)
  ...
}

Any and all assistance is greatly appreciated
